# OpenConnect (ocserv) Connected on client side, But Can not open any web page (NO INTERNET)

Tags: centos, vpn, internet, openconnect

Consider these links :
[openconnect / ocserv](https://github.com/openconnect/ocserv)
[openconnect / ocserv Installation - CentOS, RHEL, Fedora](https://ocserv.gitlab.io/www/recipes-ocserv-installation-CentOS-RHEL-Fedora.html)
I have centos 7.6 as server with **public ip**.
Also in client machine i have windows 7 os with wireless internet.
I followed these commands to install openconnect on server machine :

```
sudo yum -y install gnutls-devel libev-devel tcp_wrappers-devel pam-devel lz4-devel libseccomp-devel readline-devel libnl3-devel krb5-devel radcli-devel
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum repolist enabled
sudo yum info ocserv
sudo yum -y install ocserv
sudo ocpasswd -c /etc/ocserv/ocpasswd test
123
nano -K /etc/ocserv/ocserv.conf
```

And here is ocserv.conf file :

```
auth = "plain[passwd=/etc/ocserv/ocpasswd]"

tcp-port = 8090
udp-port = 8090

run-as-user = ocserv
run-as-group = ocserv

socket-file = ocserv.sock

chroot-dir = /var/lib/ocserv

isolate-workers = true

max-clients = 5

max-same-clients = 1

keepalive = 32400

dpd = 90

mobile-dpd = 1800

switch-to-tcp-timeout = 25

try-mtu-discovery = true

server-cert = /etc/pki/ocserv/public/server.crt
server-key = /etc/pki/ocserv/private/server.key

ca-cert = /etc/pki/ocserv/cacerts/ca.crt

cert-user-oid = 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1

tls-priorities = "NORMAL:%SERVER_PRECEDENCE:%COMPAT:-VERS-SSL3.0"

auth-timeout = 240

min-reauth-time = 300

max-ban-score = 50

ban-reset-time = 300

cookie-timeout = 300

deny-roaming = false

rekey-time = 172800

rekey-method = ssl

use-occtl = true

pid-file = /var/run/ocserv.pid

device = vpns

predictable-ips = true

default-domain = example.com

ipv4-network = 192.168.102.0
ipv4-netmask = 255.255.255.0

dns = 8.8.8.8
dns = 8.8.4.4

ping-leases = false

cisco-client-compat = true

dtls-legacy = true

user-profile = profile.xml

# Routes to be forwarded to the client. If you need the
# client to forward routes to the server, you may use the 
# config-per-user/group or even connect and disconnect scripts.
#
# To set the server as the default gateway for the client just
# comment out all routes from the server, or use the special keyword
# 'default'.

#route = 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0
#route = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
#route = fef4:db8:1000:1001::/64
```

After editing ocserv.conf i did these commands :

```
sudo systemctl start ocserv
sudo systemctl enable ocserv
sudo systemctl status ocserv
```

Now i downloaded gui software from [here](https://github.com/openconnect/openconnect-gui) on client machine.
Client machine can connect to openconnect with username `test` successfully.
But the problem is that i can not open any web page on client machine & it seems there is `NO INTERNET`.
What should i do on server machine to fix this problem?

---

**Edit After Comment :**
Firewall is off on both server & client.
I did nothing about routing or forwarding.
I am not familiar with them.
If necessary tell me what should i do about them?
Also i found this [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/851035/connected-to-openvpn-but-no-internet-connection) about my situation. But not satisfy...

Comment: Probably nothing. Is it supposed to have Internet on the first place? What is the goal of the VPN?  Full tunnel to corporate access or only for Internet access?

Comment: The goal of VPN is bypass Internet censorship in my area.

Comment: Would you please detail what firewall rules have you setup for it to work, and what you did for routing? Have you followed any tutorial? The links provided in the question do not seem particularly useful.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I enabled firewalld and tried these commands : sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --add-masquerade and systemctl reload firewalld > Now i can surf the internet on client machine easily. Why firewalld acts like that? Why it should be enable?